# Several nested tables in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator, nested-table

Is it possible to have more than one nested table per record?
For example:
In the customer row (parent), you can expand the Billing, Helpdesk, and Orders tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nested tables arent an inbuilt function of Tabulator, in the [Nested Table Example](http://tabulator.info/examples/5.1#nested-tables) you can see it uses the `rowFormatter` option to insert another table into a standard row.

You can do what ever you like in this formatter, if you want to add multiple tables, just append them to the row element